# How to use "$util.list.copyAndRetainAll(List, List)" in aws appsync resolvers?

Tags: aws-appsync

[List helpers in $util.list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html#list-helpers-in-util-list) has a brief mention of `copyAndRetainAll(List, List): List`.

[image: snapshot of aws appsync document]

In spite of the description, I'm not quite sure what 'retaining only the items specified' means.  Is the second list actually a set?  Does it step through both lists in order? Does it return the common elements after converting both lists into sets?

Does anyone have some examples of this in action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets define the method as `$util.list.copyAndRetainAll(List1, List2) : List3`, just to make it easier to identify the different lists.

`List3` will be a copy of `List1`, however, `List3` will be filtered to only contain elements that are present in `List2`. An example may make this more clear:

```
List1 = [1, 2, 3]
List2 = [2, 3, 4]
List3 = [2, 3]
```

`List3` is a copy of `List1`, however, `List2` only contains `2`, `3` and `4`, so we remove all other elements, in this case `1`, from `List1` and are left with `[2, 3]` as the value for `List3`.

Comment: Would you describe it as the 'intersection of sets (converted to/from lists)'.  ie: does order matter?  eg: If List2 were reversed into [4, 3, 2] is List3 still [2, 3] or is it [3, 2] or could be either?

Comment: Yes, I would describe it as the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)).  

If `List2` was `[4, 3, 2]`, then `List3` would still be `[2, 3]`
This is because we are making a copy of `List1` and then filtering out what is not in `List2`.  
We are **not** iterating through `List2` and picking items that exist in `List1`.